# Change the hover over and selection color for table in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table which uses class table-hover. I want to use a different color for hover and selection(by click) of a cell.

Also if a selected cell is hovered then the color chosen for selected cell should appear

I have used the following code for hover color:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr.bg-info:hover {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
}
```

But it seems that the specified color is getting used for both hover and selection of cell.

I am very much a starter to bootstrap. Please can someone help me on how to use different color for hover and selection

Comment: Try to replace tr with td, and remove .bg-info in this css selector.

Comment: You should write the complete code html as well as css.please provide fiddle to this tpe of question

Answer (score 0):

To get a event on hover:

```
   <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="bg-info">aaa</td>
          <td class="bg-info">bbb</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

    .bg-info:hover {
      background-color: #d9edf7;
    }
```

Please check is it working for you or you want any changes 
Hover :- [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/a6f1bece/2/)

HTML:-

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="bg-info">aaa</td>
  <td class="bg-info">bbb</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.bg-info').click(function(){
$('.bg-info').removeClass('bgtd');
$(this).addClass('bgtd');
})

})
```

CSS:-

```
.bgtd{
  background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

To get the background-color on click on selected of td:-[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/a6f1bece/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The default `.active` and `:hover` states as well as the contextual variants can be found starting at the line 2337 (if I'm not mistaken) inside the Bootstrap 3 CSS file.

What you will find is `.table > thead > tr > td.active` and the rest (below) is the other contextual variants (success, info, etc), then that's the right place to edit the background color.

CSS for default `.active` state:

```
.table > thead > tr > td.active,
.table > tbody > tr > td.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.active,
.table > thead > tr > th.active,
.table > tbody > tr > th.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.active,
.table > thead > tr.active > td,
.table > tbody > tr.active > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > td,
.table > thead > tr.active > th,
.table > tbody > tr.active > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > th {
  background-color /* background color for default .active state */
}
```

CSS for default `.active:hover` state:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > th {
  background-color /* background color for default .active:hover state */
}
```

You'll just have to replace the `.active` with the contextual variants (success, info, etc) or your own desired variant, then it will become something like `.table > thead > tr > td.variant`.

> OR if you know how to work with Less, then it will be a lot easier
>   cause it is already included to their source code. The file was named
>   `table-row.less` inside the mixins folder.